# Performance of std::partial_sort() versus std::sort() when sorting the whole range?

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, partial-sort

Is there a significant difference between the following two approaches? Way 1 uses `sort` or `partial_sort`, depending on the size of the vector while way 2 always uses `partial_sort`. I find way 2 more appealing because my predicate is a bit more complicated than in the example, so I don't want to repeat it. But I wonder if `partial_sort` performs worse than `sort` because it is not meant to be used to sort the whole range, which is why I tend to use way 1.

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<double> vec;
  vec.push_back(1.0);
  vec.push_back(3.0);
  vec.push_back(2.0);
  vec.push_back(5.0);
  vec.push_back(4.0);
  vec.push_back(9.0);
  const size_t numBest = 3;
  const size_t numTotal= vec.size();

#if WAY1
  if (numTotal < numBest)
  {
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::not2(std::less<double>()));
  }
  else
  {
    std::partial_sort(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + numBest, vec.end(), std::not2(std::less<double>()));
    vec.resize(numBest);
  }
#elif WAY2
  {
    const size_t numMiddle = numTotal < numBest ? numTotal : numBest;
    std::partial_sort(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + numMiddle, vec.end(), std::not2(std::less<double>()));
    vec.resize(numMiddle);
  }
#endif

  // now vec contains the largest numBest results.
  return 0;
}
```

Some testing yielded that partial_sort is significantly worse (factor of 4 in my usecase) than sort if if has to sort the whole range. This indicates that way 1 is to be preferred. It seems that partial_sort is only meant for sorting a small fraction of the whole range. I tested in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: 1) You don't have to repeat the predicate, just store it in some variable. 2) Use the simpler, more readable version and complain to your compiler vendor if that's slower. 3) visual studio 2010 is not really recent...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [sgi doc](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/partial_sort.html), `partial_sort` uses *heapsort*, `sort` uses *introsort*:

> partial_sort(first, last, last) has the effect of sorting the entire range [first, last), just like sort(first, last). They use different algorithms, however: sort uses the introsort algorithm (a variant of quicksort), and partial_sort uses heapsort. See section 5.2.3 of Knuth (D. E. Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming. Volume 3: Sorting and Searching. Addison-Wesley, 1975.), and J. W. J. Williams (CACM 7, 347, 1964). Both heapsort and introsort have complexity of order N log(N), but introsort is usually faster by a factor of 2 to 5.

So, it is normal `partial_sort` is 4 times slower than `sort`.

---

I have checked my VS2017 library, and found the implementation of `partial_sort` and `sort`. And it is similar with SGI.

#### partial_sort

```
template<class _RanIt,
    class _Pr> inline
void _Partial_sort_unchecked(_RanIt _First, _RanIt _Mid, _RanIt _Last,
        _Pr& _Pred)
{       // order [_First, _Last) up to _Mid, using _Pred
    if (_First == _Mid)
        return; // nothing to do, avoid violating _Pop_heap_hole_unchecked preconditions
    _Make_heap_unchecked(_First, _Mid, _Pred);
    for (_RanIt _Next = _Mid; _Next < _Last; ++_Next)
        if (_DEBUG_LT_PRED(_Pred, *_Next, *_First))
        {       // replace top with new largest
            _Iter_value_t<_RanIt> _Val = _STD move(*_Next);
            _Pop_heap_hole_unchecked(_First, _Mid, _Next, _STD move(_Val), _Pred);
        }
    _Sort_heap_unchecked(_First, _Mid, _Pred);
}
```

#### sort

```
template<class _RanIt,
    class _Diff,
    class _Pr> inline
void _Sort_unchecked1(_RanIt _First, _RanIt _Last, _Diff _Ideal, _Pr& _Pred)
{       // order [_First, _Last), using _Pred
    _Diff _Count;
    while (_ISORT_MAX < (_Count = _Last - _First) && 0 < _Ideal)
    {   // divide and conquer by quicksort
        pair<_RanIt, _RanIt> _Mid =
            _Partition_by_median_guess_unchecked(_First, _Last, _Pred);
        _Ideal /= 2, _Ideal += _Ideal / 2;      // allow 1.5 log2(N) divisions

        if (_Mid.first - _First < _Last - _Mid.second)
        {       // loop on second half
            _Sort_unchecked1(_First, _Mid.first, _Ideal, _Pred);
            _First = _Mid.second;
        }
        else
        {       // loop on first half
            _Sort_unchecked1(_Mid.second, _Last, _Ideal, _Pred);
            _Last = _Mid.first;
        }
    }

    if (_ISORT_MAX < _Count)
    {   // heap sort if too many divisions
        _Make_heap_unchecked(_First, _Last, _Pred);
        _Sort_heap_unchecked(_First, _Last, _Pred);
    }
    else if (2 <= _Count)
        _Insertion_sort_unchecked(_First, _Last, _Pred);        // small
}
```

Comment: Interesting - I wonder if this is true across the board (i.e. all implementations). I recall a talk about variations between sort's performance between compilers.

Comment: Except whatever the old SGI implementation of the STL does isn't necessarily the same as standard library used by OP's implementation.

Comment: I find it strange that a compiler vendor does not check for partial_sort(first, last, last) and uses sort in this case. Presumably, they want to avoid the branching.

Comment: Actually, heap-sort is a suboptimal choice for `partial_sort`: It's inner loop is roughly twice as long as the inner loop of quicksort, and half of its work is expended into building the heap, which includes *all* the elements in the entire range. I. e., the time a heap-sort base `partial_sort` takes is roughly `(1 + n/N)*T` where `T` is the time quicksort takes to sort the entire range, `n` is the length of the output range, and `N` is the length of the input range. It would have been better to just sort the entire range with quicksort instead.

Comment: sgi doc link takes me to HP site?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing requires partial_sort to be implemented in a certain way, except the guarantees of complexity

> 25.4.1.3 partial_sort [partial.sort]
>
> template void partial_sort(RandomAccessIterator first,
>    RandomAccessIterator middle, RandomAccessIterator last);
>    template 
>    void partial_sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator middle,
>    RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp);
>
> 1 Effects: Places the first middle - first sorted elements from the range [first,last) into the range [first,middle). The rest of the elements in the range [middle,last) are placed in an unspecified order.
>
> 2 Requires:
>   RandomAccessIterator shall satisfy the requirements of ValueSwappable
>   (17.6.3.2). The type of *first shall satisfy the requirements of
>   MoveConstructible (Table 20) and of MoveAssignable (Table 22).
>
> 3 Complexity: It takes approximately (last - first) * log(middle - first) comparisons

An alternative implementation could be

```
std::nth_element - average linear time
followed by
std::sort - on the reduced range begin()-nth (n log n)
```

Comment: Why do you suppose heap sort is chosen over this alternative? If `std::nth_element` is fast, it seems that this would be simpler. Also this shows that `std::partial_sort` is not orthogonal.

Comment: @wcochran heap_sort is slower than intro_sort, but if you just want to get the K highest sorted heap_sort would be faster. There is a cppcon(?) video on this topic that is worth seeing.